# Binding Mongoose models save method inside async.auto (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript, mongoose

Right now I'm working with both mongoose 3.1.1 and async 0.1.22.
But when I tried to save Mongoose models instance inside `async.auto` it just stopped working.

See the following example and try it by yourself:

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
async = require 'async'
Schema = mongoose.Schema
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId

mongoose.connect "mongodb://localhost:27017/async-test"

SmthSchema = new Schema
  data : type: String

mongoose.model 'Smth', SmthSchema
Smth = mongoose.model 'Smth'

test1 = (next) ->
  console.log '  test 1'
  smth = new Smth data: 'some data'

  async.auto
    first: (callback) ->
      smth.save callback
    second: ['first', (callback) ->
      console.log '  it works!'
      callback()]
    next

test2 = (next) ->
  console.log '  test 2'
  smth = new Smth data: 'some data'

  async.series [
    smth.save.bind smth
    (callback) ->
      console.log '  it works!'
      callback()
  ], next

test3 = (next) ->
  console.log '  test 3'
  context =
    save: (callback) -> callback null

  async.auto
    first: context.save.bind context
    second: ['first', (callback) ->
      console.log '  it works!'
      callback()]
    next

test4 = (next) ->
  console.log '  test 4'
  smth = new Smth data: 'some data'

  async.auto
    first: smth.save.bind smth
    second: ['first', (callback) ->
      console.log '  it works!'
      callback()]
    next

console.log 'running all tests'
async.series [test1, test2, test3, test4], (err) ->
  console.log err || 'all works!'
```

Resulting output:

```
running all tests
  test 1
  it works!
  test 2
  it works!
  test 3
  it works!
  test 4
```

`smth.save.bind smth` binds save function to the object it shall save. It works great in `async.series` and `async.parallel`, but not in `async.auto`.

`async.auto` saves the object to database, but it looses callback and processing stops.
But does anybody have any idea **why it happens?**

The strangest thing is than i never had any problems neither with binding anything else inside of `async.auto` nor with binding `Mongoose` save method in any other context.

I already looked into `async` code, but I still have no idea what's wrong. Now I'm planning to write an issue about it on github.

**Added 20.09.12:** I replaced `save` function with `validate` function and all worked great:

```
running all tests
  test 1
  it works!
  test 2
  it works!
  test 3
  it works!
  test 4
  it works!
all works!
```

So the problem deeply connected to mongoose `save` function.

It looks like `async.auto` breaks somewhere when it works with Mongoose method `save`. But I can't understand where and why.

Comment: Code looks OK to me.  Did you check the generated JavaScript to see if it might be a CoffeeScript issue?

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

Figured it out: If you use @dpatti's branch, it works.  I guess @caolan hasn't merged it yet (it's been 6 months or so).  I'm using async in our Node.js framework, [Sails](http://sailsjs.com), and so I'll be keeping a close eye on this, so if it gets merged in, I'll post back here.

#### Solution

In your package.json, change your async dependency to look like this:

```
"async": "git://github.com/dpatti/async.git#safe-auto"
```

Then do an `npm install` and you should be good to go.

---

Having the same problem when combining with Sequelize's save().  I think it's a function context issue—hope that helps as a start!

I'm working on a basic example that breaks and I'll report back when I have more information.  If it looks like it's actually an issue in async, I'll raise an issue in github and link to it here.

I'm also on async 0.1.22 (and Sequelize 1.5.0-beta-2, in case that helps anybody) using raw javascript (no coffee)

Comment: I already [raised an issue](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/178), but it made no effect yet.

Comment: It helped with multiple calls, but not with binding monngoose `save` method. My first example is still breaks.

Comment: Caolan just [closed my issue](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/178#issuecomment-13072547), but my problems remains. But `async 2.0.x` shall solve yours. It looks for me more like node issue now, because `function.bind` changes the behavior of `async.auto`.

Comment: It sounds like he's using `_.defer()` or `setTiemout(0)` and it's messing up the order of your call chain-- is that it?  If so, I the quickest fix would be to wrap the call to `save()` up in an asynchronous function and do `_.defer(cb)` at the bottom (where cb is your callback function from async)

Comment: The order of calls aren't messed up, it' broken. Callback in `smth.save.bind smth` newer invokes, so async flow just stucks there. I solved it by replacing `bind` with its equivalent `(cb) -> smth.save cb`. This problem appears only when I combines `async.auto`, `mongoose.Model.save` and `bind`. I'll try to play with `_.defer` and `process.nextTick`, but probably it wont help.